# Реализация интерактивного звездного неба на python

Tags: python

Доброго времени суток.

Есть задача: создать интерактивное звездное небо на питоне. В наличии архив с координатами звезд. Должна быть возможность изменения угла наклона и поворота камеры, которая стоит внутри сферы и смотрит на сие творение.

Знание языка на уровне хеллоу ворлд, времени много, терпения и мотивации в том числе. Подскажите, кому не трудно, какие библиотеки по отрисовке графики лучше использовать для данной задачи, на какие ресурсы идти курить мануалы.

Благодарю.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, все равно учить лучше на практических примерах. И, желательно, не на упражнениях из букваря, а на каком-нибудь полезном (пусть и только для себя) проекте. Так и полезнее, и интереснее:)

Comment: У меня есть реализация. Могу скинуть исходник. Если ты с матмеха Urfu

Comment: @МихаилГоробец
Да, первый курс компьютерных наук :) 
Если бы ты ещё рассказал о том, как это делал, было бы супер. Стукни на почту klarefor@yandex.ua

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> какие библиотеки лучше использовать для данной задачи

Для этого подойдут библиотеки для создания игр:

- [pygame](https://www.pygame.org/)
- [pyglet](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/pyglet-1.3-maintenance/)
- [panda3d](https://www.panda3d.org/)

pygame и pyglet не расчитаны на полноценные 3d игры, но для ваших задач будет достаточно их возможностей.

panda3d - создана для 3d, но будет сложнее для новичка.

---

Вот тут рассказывают про принципы имитации 3d графики в pygame (обратите внимание на разделы меню справа):
http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/pygame-3d-graphics-tutorial

А в этой статье автор рассказывает о том, как он упростил импорт моделей и работу с шейдерами для pyglet: https://gabdube.github.io/3d-with-python-pyglet-and-blender.html

Comment: Спасибо большое, пошел читать.